# Cocoa Lumberjack: How to log synchronously

Tags: objective-c, frameworks

Is it possible, to use the Cocoa Lumberjack framework synchronously? By default the concrete `<DDLogger>` implementation is called in a background thread by the `DDLog` class.

If it is possible, how can I configure it to be synchronously?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691399/immediately-flushing-log-statements-using-the-cocoa-lumberjack-logging-framework